# Order of instance variable assignments freezes iOS app

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, variable-assignment

In my header, I have two properties as shown below.

```
@interface HZCalendarDataSource : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *datesOnCalendar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) HZCalendarDay *currentDay;
@end
```

Then in my implementation's initializer, I have the following lines of code.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Alloc / Init instance variables.
        self.datesOnCalendar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.currentDay = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] init];

        HZCalendarDay *date = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] initOnDate:today withEventStore:self.eventStore];

        [self.datesOnCalendar addObject:date];
        // THIS line causes the app to freeze!
        // If this line is above [self.datesOnCalendar addObject:date];
        // Then it does not freeze. Why does this happen?
        self.currentDay = date;
    }

    return self;
}
```

The issue that I have, is that as shown in the comments, the `self.currentDay = date;` line freezes the app on the device. However, if I move the `self.currentDay = date;` line above the line where the date object is added to the `NSMutableArray`, then the code works just fine.

So my question is, why does the order of this matter? It should just be setting `self.currentDay` to reference the same `date` object that I added to the `NSMutableArray` correct?

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this to me, I'm not understanding it. The order doesn't really matter, so for now I've moved the troublesome line to be executed prior to adding the date object to the array, however for educational purposes, I'd like to know why this is an issue in the first place.

Edit:

After letting the app run frozen for awhile, it finally failed in Xcode after invoking [HZCalendarDateSource setCurrentDay:] 25,827 times. It failed with EXC_BAD_ACCESSS in the debugger and -[__NSArrayM countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:];

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, after re-reading the error message, it sounded like the setter was failing for some reason, even though I'm not implementing it.

However, I had wrote a helper method to loop through my array and perform some actions on an item that matches the args i provide it. I had called that helper method `setCurrentDay:`, thus I had a naming conflict. My code was getting stuck in a for-loop that I had wrote. The for-loop scanned the `self.datesOnCalendar` property, and when `self.currentDay = date;` was executed prior to adding the object to the array, the `setCurrentDay:` method would return, because the array was empty. Setting the `currentDay` after adding an object to the array was causing my `setCurrentDay:` method to get stuck in a loop.

Fix was to rename the `setCurrentDay:` method to something that does not conflict with the setter of the `currentDay` property, along with adjusting my for-loop.